# items does not show in dropdown extJS

Tags: extjs

I have a comboBox in my page? looks like this
a store

```
var sourcesStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    autoLoad:true,
    storeId: 'sourcesStore',
    listeners:Ext.ux.loaderListener,
    proxy:new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url:'/traffic/traffic_source_list/1',
    }),
    reader:new Ext.data.JsonReader(
        {
            root:'items',
            id:'source_',
            messageProperty:'msg',
            successProperty:'success',
            fields: ['id', 'name']
        },
        ['id', 'name']
    )
});
```

combo configs

```
var selectStyleComboboxConfig = {
    fieldLabel: 'My Dropdown',
    name: 'type',
    allowBlank: false,
    editable: false,
    // This is the option required for "select"-style behaviour
    triggerAction: 'all',
    typeAhead: false,
    mode: 'local',
    width: 120,
    listWidth: 140,
    hiddenName: 'traffic_source',
    /*store: [
        ['val1', 'First Value'],
        ['val2', 'Second Value']
    ],*/
    store: sourcesStore,
    readOnly: true
};
```

and here set an item

```
items: [          
      fileField,
      new Ext.form.DateField({
          xtype: 'datefield',
          fieldLabel: 'Start date',
          name: 'startdate',
          format: 'd-m-Y'
      }),
      new Ext.form.DateField({
          xtype: 'datefield',
          fieldLabel: 'End date',
          name: 'enddate',
          format: 'd-m-Y'
      }),

      new Ext.form.ComboBox(selectStyleComboboxConfig)]
```

The problem is that it does not show items to select in a dropdown. We use ext 2.3.0 in our project When I click to select I see a drop-down pretty long one, but it is empty. Im new  to extJS and I desperately need help to get through this. Sorry for my English and if some more info or details needed - just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, an answer was pretty simple. I just added

```
valueField: 'id',
displayField: 'name'
```

now its fine!